# Need to merge 2 DbContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am building my first entity framework application but i have 2 context files 1 i am using for identity and other for my other tables and for that reason it is creating 2 database 1 is in my default and other is in my database and i am trying to merge that context files in 1 please help me with this.
1 of my context is app identity. 
Things i have tried to do

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/801628/Code-First-Migration-in-Multiple-DbContext

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/2VOa140214-Entity-Framework-6-Code-First-Migrations-with-Multiple-Data-Contexts.html

Thank you  in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your context class, instead of inheriting from DbContext class, inherit from IdentityDbContext< ApplicationUser > class

Comment: Thank you for your advice i will try to implement that

Comment: Couldn't able to fix my error now it is  not able to connect to my database and also it is showing define key please give me any more suggestions if you have

Comment: Try adding this contractor to your context class...
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("<<< Connection String Key >>>", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

Comment: did you replace <<< Connection String Key >>> with your connection string?

Comment: i am able to merge that by using identityDbcontext instead of Dbcontext and all working fine but it is not making my database as mentioned in my webconfig file.